# Is a "wider concentration" correct?

Tags: word-usage

There is an issue with the eligibility of the current UK Labour leader, Jeremy Corbyn, in a upcoming vote which will decide if he will continue to lead Labour into the next election.

Corbin was voted head of the Labour party in the past general election by a wide margin of the popular vote.  However, recent events has caused him to lose support amoung his parliamentary supporters.

At issue is whether, given his popular support amoungst the wider electorate it will be necessary to get 51 supporters since only 40 voted for him during a no-confidence vote.

The [BBC reported](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-36778855)

> It is thought Mr Corbyn would struggle to amass 51 signatures because his support is *concentrated* in the party's *wider* membership.

Usually, to *concentrate*, is to decrease or narrow a range or increase an intensity of *something*, and to *widen* is to broaden or disperse *something*.

Is describing Corbyn's support as

> *concentrated* in the *wider* membership

correct?

Would it not be more correct to say his support is

> *dispersed* in the *wider* membership

since it is amoung the electorate (many people) more so than the members of parliament (not so many people)?

Comment: Voting to close because this question is based on the assumption that the BBC is fallible.  :)

Comment: no, not dispersed. There is a wider membership and it is concentrated at that place or point.

Answer (score 1):

[*concentrate*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/concentrate) used here is something like *focus*:

> 1. to come or cause to come to a single purpose or aim ⇒ *to concentrate one's hopes on winning*

So you could write the phrase like:

> It is thought Mr Corbyn would struggle to amass 51 signatures because his support is **focused** in the party's wider membership.

Comment: You could ask the same thing about focused, though... can something that's "focused" be "wide"? When you think of flashlight beams, the two options are "focused" for a narrow beam or "wide" for a broad beam.

Comment: They are modifying different things. *concentrated/focused* modifies "support", while *wider* modifies "membership".

Comment: @user3169 is correct.  In this particular case, "wider membership" = the general public members of the party, as opposed to the MPs.

Comment: The wider membership may well be taken to mean the *fringe* membership -- excluding the core membership.  If his support is concentrated around the party's edges, then he's missing the support of the central majority of that party.